# RxAndroidBle: Changelog / Release notes?

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm actually using version 1.1.0 of RxAndroidBle, the latest version is currently 1.3.3.

I'd like to know the changes between these two versions, but I couldn't find any release notes in Github or in the website. So that I can tell if it's worth upgrading in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [changelog](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) from Github. ;-)